# Query sql on string

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server

I have a db with users that have all this record .

I would like to do a query on a data like

```
CN=aaa, OU=Domain,OU=User, OU=bbbbbb,OU=Department, OU=cccc, OU=AUTO, DC=dddddd, DC=com
```

and I need to group all users by the same ou=department.

How can I do the select with the substring to search a department??

My idea for the solution is to create another table that is like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------
ldapstring                           | society | site
---------------------------------------------------
"CN=aaa, OU=Domain,OU=User, OU=bbbbbb,OU=Department, OU=cccc, OU=AUTO, DC=dddddd, DC=com" | societyName1 | societySite1
```

and my idea is to compare the string with these on the new table with the tag like but how can I take the society and site when the like string occurs?????

Please help me

Comment: We need to see your table structures, and maybe some data. Also, do you wish to limit the result set based on the criteria above, is that all **AND** or **OR** conditions?

Comment: That looks like an LDAP query. Perhaps your data comes from an LDAP backend?

Comment: is it microsoft sql server or mysql? i don't see it, or is it just me?

Comment: yes it's an ldap query, but the ldap data now is in a mssql db

Answer (score 3):

You could always do `ColumnName LIKE '%OU=Department%'`.

Regardless, I think this needs to be normalized into a better table, if possible. Multivalue columns should be avoided as much as possible.

IF you aren't dealing with a database, the next best thing would be a regular expression.

Comment: Normalisation is the best way to do it.

Comment: Normalize the minimum... maybe just break out the 'OU' column.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should look into MySQL regular expressions. I, myself, have never used it, but just wanted to suggest it :-)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html